# Brother saying kaddish after sheloshim

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, chazzan-prayer-leader

A sibling who passed away without having children but his brother takes the responsibility to say Kaddish for the eleven months.

Is the brother allowed to lead prayers from the amud if he is acting like an avel or does he risk giving other people the impression that

- One says kaddish for 11 months for a brother instead of 30 days
- An avel can daven for the amud during Chol Hamoed etc.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501). Hope to see you around!